# continuous auto-correlation implies r.p. is mean square continuous

Tags: stochastic-processes

Show that the random process X(t) is **mean square continuous** if and only if its auto-correlation function $R_X(t_1, t_2) = E\Big[ X(t_1)~X(t_2)\Big]$ is continuous when $t_1=t_2=t$.

---

First part of proof proves that X(t) is mean square continous:

A random process X(t) is **mean square continuous** if:

$$L = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} ~~E\bigg\{~ \Big(X(t+\varepsilon) - X(t) \Big)^2~ \bigg\} = 0$$

Thus:

$$L = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} E\Bigg\{ \Big[(X(t+\varepsilon)-X(t)\Big]^2\Bigg\}$$

$$L = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} E\Bigg\{ X^2(t+\varepsilon) -2~X(t+\varepsilon)~X(t) + X^2(t) \Bigg\}$$

$$L = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \Bigg(R_X(t+\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon) - 2 R_X(t+\varepsilon,t) + R_X(t,t) \Bigg)$$

$$L = R_X(t, t) - 2 R_X(t,t) + R_X(t,t)$$

$$L = 0$$

Therefore process X(t) is mean square continuous.

---

The next part of the proof says to consider the following equation:

$$\begin{aligned}&R_X(t+\varepsilon_1, t+ \varepsilon_2) - R_X(t,t) \\&= E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_1) - X(t)\Big] \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_2) - X(t)\Big] \Bigg\} \\ &+ E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_1)-X(t) \Big]~X(t)\Bigg\} \\&+ E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_2)-X(t) \Big]~X(t)\Bigg\}\end{aligned}\tag{1}$$

Then, Applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to (1), we obtain:

$$\begin{aligned}&R_X(t+\varepsilon_1, t+ \varepsilon_2) - R_X(t,t) \\&\le \Bigg(E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_1) - X(t)\Big]^2 \Bigg\} E \Bigg\{\Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_2) - X(t)\Big]^2 \Bigg\}\Bigg)^{1/2} \\ &+ \Bigg(E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_1)-X(t) \Big]^2\Bigg\}~E\Bigg\{X^2(t)\Bigg\}\Bigg)^{1/2} \\&+ \Bigg(E\Bigg\{ \Big[ X(t+\varepsilon_2)-X(t) \Big]^2\Bigg\}~E\Bigg\{X^2(t)\Bigg\}\Bigg)^{1/2}\end{aligned}\tag{2}$$

Thus, if X(t) is mean square continuous, then we have:

$$\lim \limits_{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2 \to 0} R_X(t+\varepsilon_1,t+\varepsilon_2) - R_X(t,t) =0$$

Thus, $R_X(t_1, t_2)$ is continuous.  This completes the proof.

---

**Now for my Question**:

How did they come up with equation (1)?  It seems like they just pulled it out of thin air.

---

Here's a scan from the book:

[image: example]

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right... but, here's my work:

(1) In Calculus, a function f(t) is said to be a **continuous function**, if for every value of t, the following holds:

$$\lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \Big(  f(t+\varepsilon) - f(t) \Big) = 0$$

And a random process X(t) is **mean square continuous** if:

$$\lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \Bigg(  E\Bigg[\Big(X(t+\varepsilon) - X(t)\Big)^2\Bigg] \Bigg) = 0$$

---

(2) The **Mean Square** $E[X^2(t)]$ is the same as the **autocorrelation** function:

$$R_X(t_1, t_2)=E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$$

when both time parameters at set to the same time instant, that is:

$$R_X(t,t) = E[X^2(t)]$$

---

(3) If we apply this definition of a continuous function to the means square $E[X^2(t)]$, then we have:

$$\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \Bigg(E\Big[X^2(t+\varepsilon)\Big] - E\Big[X^2(t)\Big] \Bigg)= 0$$

then breaking epsilon $\varepsilon$ into two variables that approach zero ($\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2$) ... just to be fancy:

$$\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \Bigg(E\Big[X(t+\varepsilon)X(t+\varepsilon)\Big] - E\Big[X(t)X(t)\Big] \Bigg)= 0$$

$$\lim \limits_{\begin{matrix}\epsilon_1 \to 0  \\ \epsilon_2 \to 0\end{matrix}} \Bigg(E\Big[X(t+\varepsilon_2)X(t+\varepsilon_1)\Big] - E\Big[X(t)X(t)\Big] \Bigg)= 0$$

Then writing mean square $E[X^2(t)]$ in terms of Autocorrelation $R_X(t_1,t_2)$.

$$\lim \limits_{\begin{matrix}\epsilon_1 \to 0  \\ \epsilon_2 \to 0\end{matrix}} \Big(R_X(t+\varepsilon_1, t+\varepsilon_2) - R_X(t,t) \Big)= 0$$

If this relation is true, then it proves that the auto-correlation function is continuous at $R_X(t,t)= E[X^2(t)]$, and that the mean square $E[X^2(t)]$ is also continuous, if R_X(t,t) is continuous.

And if X(t) is WSS, it proves that autocorrelation is continuous at $R_X(t-t) = R_X(0) = E[X^2(t)]$, and that the mean square $E[X^2(t)]$ is also continuous, if R_X(0) is continuous.